# How in Python do i use a GCP enum?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, enums, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-python

How do I use the GCP [enum](https://jskeet.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.TextAnnotation.Types.DetectedBreak.Types.BreakType.html#fields) `Text​Annotation.​Types.​Detected​Break.​Types.​Break​Type` in my python code?
I assume I import it somehow, but do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're linking to the .NET docs, but asking about Python. If you want to use these enums from Python, you'll first need to install the Google Cloud Vision client library from PyPI:

```
$ pip install google-cloud-vision
```

Then you can access the enums like this:

```py
>>> from google.cloud import vision
>>> vision.TextAnnotation.DetectedBreak.BreakType
<enum 'BreakType'>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I could tell `vision.TextAnnotation.DetectedBreak.BreakType` is part of the `vision` package? In other words, where it is documented?

Comment: Ah [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.TextAnnotation.Types.DetectedBreak.Types.BreakType.html)